# Python script runs but does not work and no errors are thrown

Tags: python-3.6, discord.py

This program is an API based program that has been working for a few months and all of a sudden has went days without pushing anything to Discord. The script looks fine in CMD, but no errors are being thrown. I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate possible issues such as an API instability issue or something obvious. The program is supposed to go to the site www.bitskins.com and pull skins based on parameters set and push them as an embed to a Discord channel every 10 minutes.

There are two files that run this program.
Here is the one that uses Bitskins API (bitskins.py):

```
import requests, json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Item:
    def __init__(self, item):
        withdrawable_at= item['withdrawable_at']
        price= float(item['price'])
        self.available_in= withdrawable_at- datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        if self.available_in< 0:
            self.available= True
        else:
            self.available= False
        self.suggested_price= float(item['suggested_price'])
        self.price= price
        self.margin= round(self.suggested_price- self.price, 2)
        self.reduction= round((1- (self.price/self.suggested_price))*100, 2)
        self.image= item['image']
        self.name= item['market_hash_name']
        self.item_id= item['item_id']

    def __str__(self):
        if self.available:
            return "Name: {}\nPrice: {}\nSuggested Price: {}\nReduction: {}%\nAvailable Now!\nLink: https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(self.name, self.price, self.suggested_price, self.reduction, self.item_id)
        else:
            return "Name: {}\nPrice: {}\nSuggested Price: {}\nReduction: {}%\nAvailable in: {}\nLink: https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(self.name, self.price, self.suggested_price, self.reduction, str(timedelta(seconds= self.available_in)), self.item_id)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.reduction < other.reduction
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.reduction > other.reduction


def get_url(API_KEY, code):
    PER_PAGE= 30 # the number of items to retrieve. Either 30 or 480.
    return "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_inventory_on_sale/?api_key="+ API_KEY+"&code=" + code + "&per_page="+ str(PER_PAGE)

def get_data(url):
    r= requests.get(url)
    data= r.json()
    return data

def get_items(code, API_KEY):
    url= get_url(API_KEY, code)
    try:
        data= get_data(url)
        if data['status']=="success":
            items= []
            items_dic= data['data']['items']
            for item in items_dic:
                tmp= Item(item)
                if tmp.reduction>=25 and tmp.price<=200:    # Minimum discount and maximum price to look for when grabbing items. Currently set at minimum discount of 25% and maxmimum price of $200.
                    items.append(tmp)
            return items
        else:
            raise Exception(data["data"]["error_message"])
    except:
        raise Exception("Couldn't connect to BitSkins.")
# my_token = pyotp.TOTP(my_secret)
# print(my_token.now()) # in python3
```

And here is the file with Discord's API (solution.py):

```
#!/bin/env python3.6
import bitskins
import discord
import pyotp, base64, asyncio
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

TOKEN= "Not input for obvious reasons"

API_KEY= "Not input for obvious reasons"

my_secret= 'Not input for obvious reasons'

client = discord.Client()

def get_embed(item):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=item.name, url= "https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(item.item_id), color=0xA3FFE8)
    embed.set_author(name="Skin Bot", url="http://www.reactor.gg/",icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1050077525471158272/4_R8PsrC_400x400.jpg")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=item.image)
    embed.add_field(name="Price:", value="${}".format(item.price))
    embed.add_field(name="Discount:", value="{}%".format(item.reduction), inline=True)
    if item.available:
        tmp= "Instantly Withdrawable"
    else:
        tmp= str(timedelta(seconds= item.available_in))
    embed.add_field(name="Availability:", value=tmp, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Suggested Price:", value="${}".format(item.suggested_price), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Profit:", value="${}".format(item.margin), inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by Aqyl#0001 | {}".format(datetime.now()), icon_url="https://www.discordapp.com/assets/6debd47ed13483642cf09e832ed0bc1b.png")
    return embed

async def status_task(wait_time= 60* 5):
    while True:
        print("Updated on: {}".format(datetime.now()))
        code= pyotp.TOTP(my_secret)
        try:
            items= bitskins.get_items(code.now(), API_KEY)
            for item in items:
                await client.send_message(client.get_channel("656913641832185878"), embed=get_embed(item))
        except:
            pass
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    wait_time= 60 * 10 # 10 mins in this case

    print('CSGO BitSkins Bot')
    print('Made by Aqyl#0001')
    print('Version 1.0.6')
    print('')
    print('Logged in as:')
    print(client.user.name)
    print('------------------------------------------')
    client.loop.create_task(status_task(wait_time))

try:
    client.run(TOKEN)
except:
    print("Couldn't connect to the Discord Server.")
```

Comment: You have a general exception (`except: pass`) on your program. Isn't it the issue? You can check by using `traceback.print_exc()`

Comment: @AlexanderSantos thanks so much! I didn't even realize.

Comment: Np. I will reply as answer to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

You have a general exception, this will lead to catching exceptions that you really don't want to catch.

```
try:
    items= bitskins.get_items(code.now(), API_KEY)
    for item in items:
        await client.send_message(client.get_channel("656913641832185878"), embed=get_embed(item))
except:
    pass
```

This is the same as catching any exception that appears there (Exceptions that inherit `BaseException`

To avoid those problems, you should always catch specific exceptions. (i.e. `TypeError`).

Example:

```
try:
    raise Exception("Example exc")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception caught! {e}")
```